# SSIS Import Packages with Oracle connection failed

Tags: oracle, ssis

I have made a working SSIS project with SQL Server Data Tools for Visual Studio 2012 64 bit environment. I have made SSIS projects before but this is the first project which includes Oracle Destination. (Oracle connection)
I have installed the Oracle 64 and 32 bit drivers (ver.11g) and TNS names are configured ok on my work PC.
Overall the project works fine when I debug it on my PC in Visual Studio.
When I try to save the package file and then in (Production MS Server 2012) MS SQL Server Management Studio upload the file with "IMPORT PACKAGES" wizard I get this error: 0XC0010014 on wizards select package step.

The package failed to load due error 0xC0010014 "One or more error occured...
This occurs when CPackage::LoadFromXML fails.

Oracle drivers are installed and configured same on my PC and production server.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Anyone? Ideas? If I use Native Ole DB/Microsoft OLE DB Provider for Oracle, Package IMPORT is succesfull but the execute gives error. If I use any other SSIS Oracle connection type, IMPORT gives error which is above.